# FFMPEG add circular mask to videos, convert to black and white and concatenate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Hello everyone i'm a beginner and i would appreciate your help.

I'm making a mobile application that generates custom video resumes based on the user's videos taken from his phone, the user has to upload 5 different videos to the server from the mobile application, in the server side i want to :

- Add a .png circular mask to each video.
- Make each video black and white.
- Concatenate the videos with other already existing title videos 
  (e.g [userVideo1] [title1] [userVideo2] [title2]...) [Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBsl3.png)

  [Edit : I would like more features]
- Add background music
- Add watermark logo in the middle
- Remove silent footage from the beginning and from the end
- Some input videos might be rotated, i want to rotate videos back to normal if they are rotated.

So far i managed to add the circular mask, make the videos black and white and concatenate 3 videos including a premade title video, but the second user video has no sound in the output.

This is the script i ended up with :

```
ffmpeg -i uservid1.mov -i uservid2.mp4 -i mask.png -i title1.mp4  -preset 
ultrafast -filter_complex "

[2:v][0:v]scale2ref[s1][s2];     
[s2][s1]overlay[vid1];  
[2:v][1:v]scale2ref[s3][s4]; 
[s4][s3]overlay[vid2];  
[vid1]hue=s=0[v0]; 
[vid2]hue=s=0[v1];  
[v0]scale=720x400[in0]; 
[v1]scale=720x400[in1]; 
[3:v]scale=720x400[in3]; 
[in0]setsar=sar=0[final0]; 
[in1]setsar=sar=0[final1];      
[in3]setsar=sar=0[final3]; 
[final0][final3][final1]concat=n=3;"

-codec:a copy finalCV.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i uservid1.mov -i uservid2.mp4 -i mask.png -i title1.mp4 -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc 
-filter_complex
"[2:v][0:v]scale2ref[s1][s2];
 [s2][s1]overlay,hue=s=0,scale=720x400,setsar=1[v0];
 [2:v][1:v]scale2ref[s3][s4];
 [s4][s3]overlay,hue=s=0,scale=720x400,setsar=1[v1];
 [3:v]scale=720x400,setsar=1[v3];
 [v0][0:a][v3][4:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1"
-preset ultrafast finalCV.mp4
```

The audio needs to be concatenated as well. I assume the title video has no audio, so I've set up a dummy silent 1-second stream as the last input.

Comment: Yes indeed the title vid does not have audio. Thank you so so much, it works!

Comment: I have added some more features, i would really appreciate if you could help me with those too, thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: This is what i got from typing "ffmpeg -version" `ffmpeg version N-90313-gb173e03536 built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC) libavutil 56. 9.100 libavcodec 58. 14.100 libavformat 58. 10.100 libavdevice 58. 2.100 libavfilter 7. 13.100 libswscale 5. 0.102 libswresample 3. 0.101 libpostproc 55. 0.100`